# How to concatenate fields in select statements using Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm wondering how to concatenate two fields in DQL select statement with some literal between.

I have this for now but no luck...

```
$qb
            ->select('season.id, concat(competition.name, '-',season.name) AS specs')
            ->leftJoin('season.competition', 'competition')
            ->where('season.name LIKE :q')
            ->setParameter('q', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->setMaxResults($p)
        ;
```

Comment: i try and the [concat DQL function](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) work fine. What problem do you have?

Answer (score 5):

We cannot send three arguments here, but we can do it like this,

```
$em = \Zend_Registry::get('em');
        $qb_1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $q_1 = $qb_1->select( "reprt_abs.id" )
        ->addSelect( "CONCAT( CONCAT(reporter.firstname, ' '),  reporter.lastname)" )
        ->from( '\Entities\report_abuse', 'reprt_abs' )
        ->leftJoin( 'reprt_abs.User', 'reporter' )
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This part is that what you want:

> $qb_1->select( "reprt_abs.id" )
>             ->addSelect( "CONCAT( CONCAT(reporter.firstname, ' '),  reporter.lastname)" )

Following is the output at my side:

```
array (size=19)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      1 => string 'Jaskaran Singh' (length=14)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 9
      1 => string 'Harsimer Kaur' (length=14)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 12
      1 => string 'Jaskaran Singh' (length=14)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 16
      1 => string 'Jaskaran Singh' (length=14)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 19
      1 => string 'Jaskaran Singh' (length=14)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 4
      1 => string 'shilpi jaiswal' (length=14)
```

Comment: For me 3+ `CONCAT` arguments works (Doctrine 2.5.4). I had different issue - it cannot be used quotes (`"`) inside `CONCAT`, only apostrophes (`'`). E.g. `CONCAT("a", "b")` did not work. But it shouldn't be OP case.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I use in Doctrine 2.4+ on MySQL database PDO Platform:

```
$concat = new Query\Expr\Func('CONCAT', $name[$k]);
$concat .= ' as ' . $k;
$concat = str_replace(',', ',\' \',', $concat);
$this->query->addSelect($concat);
```

So $name[$k] is an array of fields, as many as you wish.  I then add some spacing between the fields with the str_replace. $k is the name of the concat field, so the result of $concat is

```
"CONCAT(p.email,' ', h.phoneNumber,' ', p.officialName) as details"
```